# Why is Pagination causing my DropDown List filter to reset?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, pagination

I am in ASP.NET MVC and I am displaying data from my database to my screen. I have a dropdown list at the top of the page to filter the data based on 2 options(option 1 and option 2).

I have added AJAX to load a PartialView that will update the data on the screen based on the filter.

My problem is, whenever I change a page with pagination, my filter gets reset to the first option, Option 1.

For example, the page loads, and I switch the dropdown list filter to option 2. Option 2 data correctly displays on the screen. I try to go to page 2 via pagination. The data shows page 2, but the filter has switched back to Option 1, and option 1 data is now showing(it should of stayed on Option 2, and I should of seen data for Option 2).

Below are my View and Partial View:

View

```
//Dropdown list with 2 options to filter data
@Html.DropDownList("Filter", new SelectList(Model.comboBoxFilerValues), new    { @id = "filterDropdown" }) 

//Everything in this div gets reloaded by AJAX with the partial view
<div id="reportTable">
<table id="lifeUsage">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            //print table header
            @foreach (var column in Model.columnHeaders) columns
            {
                <td>
                    @column
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
        //print data with paged list for pagination
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.plist)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td>@cell</td>
                }
            </tr>

        }
</table>
//pagination page control
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.plist, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
</div>


@section scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

       $('#filterDropdown').change(function () {

            var filter = $('#filterDropdown').val();//value selected from droplist list 

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/FilterReport",
                data: {
                    filterValue: filter
                    }
            }).done(function (partialViewResult) {   
                $('#reportTable').html(partialViewResult);//load new partial view with filtered data


            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Partial View

```
<table id="lifeUsage">
<thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var column in Model.columnHeaders)
        {
            <td>
                @column
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
</thead>

@foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.plist)
{
    <tr>
        @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
        {
            <td>@cell</td>
        }
    </tr>

}
</table>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.plist, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Can anyone see why my Dropdown list filter gets reset to Option 1 whenever I switch pages?

EDIT

Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    QueryService data = new QueryService("connection");

    public ActionResult Index(string filter, int? page)
    {
        DataTableModel lifeUsageReport = new DataTableModel();
        lifeUsageReport.columnHeaders = new List<string>();
        lifeUsageReport.list = data.GetLifeUsageReport(filter).Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList();
        lifeUsageReport.plist = new PagedList<DataRow>(lifeUsageReport.list, page ?? 1, 10);
        lifeUsageReport.comboBoxFilerValues = new List<string>();
        foreach(DataColumn column in data.GetLifeUsageReport(filter).Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            lifeUsageReport.columnHeaders.Add(column.Caption);
        }
        foreach(DataRow row in data.GetLifeUsageReport(filter).Tables[1].Rows)
        {
            lifeUsageReport.comboBoxFilerValues.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
        }
        return View(lifeUsageReport);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FilterReport(string filterValue, int? page)
    {
        List<string> headers = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataColumn column in data.GetLifeUsageReport(filterValue).Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            headers.Add(column.Caption);
        }


        FilteredReportViewModel model = new FilteredReportViewModel()
        {
            plist = new PagedList<DataRow>   (data.GetLifeUsageReport(filterValue).Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList(), page ?? 1, 10),
            columnHeaders = new List<string>(headers)

        };

        return PartialView("_FilteredReportPartialView",model);
    }
```

Comment: Please share your controller's code.

Comment: @JCM added controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Reeggiie: The thing is that you are calling your Index Action on pagination, thus you will return your whole view over and over again. What you have to do is check if there's an Ajax request.

On your Index action check whether it's an Ajax request or not:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return PartialView("_FilteredReportPartialView", model);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would this @Ajax.PageLinks replace my @Html.PagedListPager?

Comment: Also, my view is not recognizing PageLinks in @Ajax.Pagelinks()

Comment: @Ajax.PageLinks is a custom way to do pagination, I'll edit my answer, try to just check the "if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())" to return your PartialView or not.

Comment: Will this work if im using @Html.PagedListPage? does this count as an AjaxRequest?

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I just had to set up an ajax function to call my Index method whenever a page is clicked, then I applied your solution at the top of the index method.